# Unit testing and coverage-ing a function using multiprocessing.Process() in python

Tags: python, code-coverage, python-multiprocessing, python-unittest, coverage.py

I am trying to test a function that might crash, using multiprocessing.Process(). The code written below restarts the call if the function doesn't respond ideally within 10 minutes which is working completely fine, even the `self.assert...` tests are working fine. The problem comes out to be with the coverage, for some reason, running coverage over my files shows that `my_func` is being called but nothing inside it is getting covered while testing whereas the tests (which require the whole function to be executed without crashing) are passing.

```
        while True:
           p = multiprocessing.Process(
               target=my_func, args=(return_dict) # return_dict to get the return values
           )
           p.start()
           p.join(600)

           if p.is_alive():
               print(
                   "Taking too long, "
                   + "KILLING IT and starting AGAIN."
               )
               p.kill()
               p.join()
           else:
               break
```

Is there something that I am doing wrong? Please let me know if the information seems incomplete, I'll add my tests and the function then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Reference link](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-37354)

For coverage to cover code running in sub-processes you need to actually specify it.

1. Add `import coverage` import statement in your file
2. Add `coverage.process_startup()` on top of every `multiprocessing.Process()` statement, in my case something like this -

   coverage.process_startup()

   p = multiprocessing.Process(
   target=my_func, args=(return_dict)
   )

   ....rest of the code
3. Create a `.coveragerc` file in your root directory and add the following lines to specify covering subprocesses and multiprocessing.

   [run]

   concurrency=multiprocessing
4. Set a path variable called `COVERAGE_PROCESS_START` to store the location of `.coveragerc` file

   set COVERAGE_PROCESS_START=%cd%\.coveragerc    // Windows

   export COVERAGE_PROCESS_START=$PWD/.coveragerc    // UNIX/LINUX
5. You're all set, run the tests using `coverage run -m unittest`, notice how now there are more than 1 coverage report files generated. To combine them run `coverage combine` and finally for the report run `coverage report`

Comment: This doesn't work for me. One ?: should it be `coverage run -m pytest`? When I do all this, I get a weird exception: SystemExit: ExitCode.OK. Actual coverage is far lower than usual. All the tests pass, but the coverage report is garbage. Any ideas? I am on a Mac - don't know if that makes any difference.

Comment: I ended up giving a talk on this - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iSwvTDy_IKw&list=PLqtzN042QpfdkQbkOlwtEJMBGZHHsvimo&index=50

The above answer still works for me but it has some redundant information (some files that are not required, etc.)